# Android: Type MenuPopup is inaccessible in this context due to: MenuPopup

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to access `MenuPopup` instance from my own package namespace . i have no idea about this error, i am tiro :(  ...

[PopupMenu Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Code:

```
class XMenuPopup { 
// .... 
internal val mPopup: MenuPopupHelper 

// ... 
fun show() { 

    // Error notice is here 
    // Type MenuPopup is inaccessible in this context due to: MenuPopup 
    mPopup.popup 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you show a minimal set of your code that reproduces the issue? Also not sure why this is tagged Java and Kotlin.

Comment: Of course . it is Kotlin as below . `class XMenuPopup { // .... internal val mPopup: MenuPopupHelper // ... fun show() {  mPopup.popup  // Error notice is here } } '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that class you want to use is private and it's not accessible in this context. Maybe you should try to use inheritance like below

```
class XMenuPopup : MenuPopup {
```

Check also: http://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-custom-views/

Hope it would help